# writing a csv file by column in pandas throws error

Tags: python, csv, pandas, pandas-datareader

I am reading and writing a csv file using pandas.

I am reading a csv file column by column and writing it to a seperate csv file by column by column reading works fine but while writing a csv file it thorws error

```
import pandas
f1 = open('artist_links','a')
data_df = pandas.read_csv('upc1.upcs_result.csv')
#data_wr = pandas.to_csv('test.csv')

df = data_df['one']
dd = data_df['two']
header = ["df", "dd"]
df.to_csv("test.csv",columns = header)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merge.py", line 9, in <module>
    df.to_csv("test.csv",columns = header)
TypeError: to_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'
```

But there is a column argument actully here [pandas library](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

How could i make this program work(Writing column by column)

Comment: What's your pandas version?

Comment: 0.13.1 @AlexanderHuszagh

Comment: There's your issue. I'll post an answer.

Comment: could you provide a sample of the csv you are reading

Comment: df.to_csv("test.csv",header= header) try this and see

Comment: @VigneshKalai i get this error "ValueError: Writing 1 cols but got 2 aliases
"

Comment: df has data for only one column right

Comment: @VigneshKalai yes you are correct

Comment: Then only give one header

Comment: but df has one column and dd is another column i want to write dd in anohter column

Comment: You can refer to the detailed method definition from [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/frame.py)

Comment: @chancyWu pagenot found

Comment: why dont you combine df and dd then right I am not so familiar with panda but there is a way to combine

Comment: how could i combine it?

Comment: Header has a different function. It's either a boolean to include the header names or a list of names to include. This answer is incorrect. It does not change what columns are exported.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

For example:

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(5), columns=range(5))
>>> df.to_csv(header=[1,5])
ValueError: Writing 5 cols but got 2 aliases

Comment: Seriously: the answer is: Upgrade Pandas. If you are using documentation written for new code and want to use archaic modules, you will have more issues. There are workarounds, such as exporting a series to list and then exporting that to CSV, but the whole point is the use the optimized functionality already in place.

Answer (score 2):

Changes in v0.16.0

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew.html

cols as the keyword for the csv and Excel writers was replaced with columns.

Try cols instead or upgrade pandas.

Instead of:

```
df.to_csv("test.csv", columns=header)
```

Use:

```
df.to_csv("test.csv", cols=header)
```

Edit: Either way you should upgrade. Sincerely. If the error is a keyword argument and you are basing your method off of documentation for the most recent version on software written over 1.5 years ago, with substantial changes made since then, you should upgrade.

EDIT2: If you're desperate to make life difficult for yourself and continue using outdated functions and try to use new features, you could do workarounds. This is not recommended, since some stuff may be a lot more subtle and throw exceptions when you least expect it.

You could... do...

```
lst = []
for column in header:
    s = df[column]
    # export all to list and nested
    lst.append(s.tolist())
# zip resulting lists to tuples
zipped = zip(*lst)
# export them as a CSV.
print '\n'.join([','.join(i) for i in zipped])
```

EDIT3: Much simpler, but you could also do:

```
df2 = df[header]   # return copy
df2.to_csv()
```

Comment: Can you upgrade your pandas version?

Seriously: 0.13.1 was ages ago. You're using documentation for new functions on software written 1.5 years ago.

>>> a = pd.DataFrame(index=range(5), columns=range(5))
>>> a.to_csv(columns=[1,5])
',1,5\n0,,\n1,,\n2,,\n3,,\n4,,\n'

Comment: so how could i upgrade it?

Comment: If you have pip you can do:
sudo pip install pandas --upgrade

Comment: That's assuming you're installing on a Mac OS X or Linux system (*Nix system), and that you have pip and you are installing to a root location.

If you're on Windows, grab a binary here:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Install pip and then install the wheel (if you don't have it):
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: I just got this error with version 17.1, interesting. the same code works elsewhere too